# Restore iPhone SMS history from Mac Messages without iPhone backup

Tags: iphone, icloud, backup, messages, sms

I recently reimaged my iPhone, however I forgot to check my SMS history before deleting my original backup. I assumed, incorrectly, that it would sync via iCloud, or by the SMS Forwarding feature that brings these messages into Mac OS X Messages. So, I have no `sms.db`, but I do have `chat.db` and the supporting Attachments. Extensive searching turns up nothing.

How hard is it to translate a `chat.db` file into an `sms.db` file suitable for restoring from an iPhone backup? Major surgery? Minor hacking? Rename the file?

Answer (score 1):

This will surely frustrate later arrivals who only have `chat.db` available, but I later realized I have other iOS devices with up-to-date Messages. I extracted `sms.db` and Attachments from those backups (using [iPhone Backup Extractor](http://supercrazyawesome.com)), merged them into my latest iPhone backup (using [iBackupBot](http://www.icopybot.com/itunes-backup-manager.htm)), and restored the backup. I'd suggest turning on airplane mode to avoid receiving texts in the backup/restore interim.

[This tutorial](http://9to5mac.com/2016/04/09/how-to-backup-restore-sms-texts-imessages-clean-ios-install/) provides details on where these files go.